# Spring Boot High Memory into OutOfMemory error

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, out-of-memory

I am sorry for the long post, but I believe It is important to mention everything related to the issue.

I am dealing with a requirement for my webservice that sends out notifications for **20k+** users at a time. Since this is quite a heavy task, I thought that having it Async was probably the best approach as it will take some time to process the data. This feature is available for a vast majority of users on the platform, hence there can be multiple requests at once. The amount of users that will receive a notification can vary from **1k** to **20k+**. Since the request processing takes quite a long time - I basically create a notification, assign it to the correct talents and then send it out in waves. This feature alone seems to have a massive impact on performance when there is multiple concurrent requets for notifications active at the same time and I end up with an out of memory error. I am not sure if this can be optimized at all, or If I should just perhaps choose a completely different approach to everything. I apologize for the long post but I believe it important that I mention everything.

I designed the system to act as follows:

- I receive a notification request, which is created in a separate table
- I receive a token that indicates which users should get the notification
- I fetch the users via a mapped class that is used as a predicate inside of a findAll method (QueryDSL)
- I created a relational table taht contains the notificationId, talentId and an extra 'sent' column. Every talent that should receive the message is added to this table along with the notificationId
- I have a @Scheduled method that picks up a portion of the notification/talent relations and sends out the notification periodically

My Async configuration class is as follows:

```
@Component
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfiguration implements AsyncConfigurer {


    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();

        executor.setMaxPoolSize(5);
        executor.setCorePoolSize(5);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("asyncExec-");
        executor.initialize();

        return executor;
    }

    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        return (ex, method, params) -> {
            System.out.println("Exception with message :" + ex.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Method :" + method);
            System.out.println("Number of parameters :" + params.length);
        };
    }
}
```

My user entity has the following mapping:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "talent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<TalentRoleNotificationRelations> roleNotifications;
```

My notification has the following mapping:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "roleNotification", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<TalentRoleNotificationRelations> roleNotifications;
```

And my relational table entity is as follows:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TalentRoleNotificationRelations implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private TalentRoleNotificationIdentity identity;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("talentId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "talent_id")
    private Talent talent;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("roleNotificationId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_notification_id")
    private RoleNotification roleNotification;

    private Boolean sent;
}
```

And the composite key identity:

```
@Embeddable
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Data
public class TalentRoleNotificationIdentity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "talent_id")
    private String talentId;
    @Column(name = "role_notification_id")
    private String roleNotificationId;
}
```

This mapping was done following the guide [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many) which indicates how a many to many relation with an extra column should be implemented.

And the actual process of creating the notification

Controller method:

```
@PostMapping(value = "notify/{searchToken}/{roleId}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public RoleNotificationInfo notifyTalentsOfNewRole(@PathVariable String searchToken, @PathVariable String roleId) {
        var roleProfileInfo = (RoleProfileInfo) Optional.ofNullable(searchToken)
                    .map(token -> searchFactory.fromToken(token, RoleProfileInfo.class))
                    .orElse(null);

        return productionService.notifyTalentsOfMatchingRole(roleProfileInfo, roleId);
    }
```

Service method: (**This is where I believe the issue is, as well as a very bad use of a many to many table mapping?)**

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    @Async
    public RoleNotificationInfo notifyTalentsOfMatchingRole(RoleProfileInfo roleProfileInfo, String roleId) {
        var predicate = Optional.ofNullable(userService.getPredicate(roleProfileInfo)).orElse(new BooleanBuilder());
        var role = roleDao.findById(roleId).orElseThrow(NoSuchRole::new);

        var isNotificationLimitReached = isNotificationLimitReached(roleId);
        if (!isNotificationLimitReached) {
            var notificationBody = notificationBodyDao.findById(NotificationBodyIdentifier.MATCHING_ROLE)
                    .orElseThrow(NoSuchNotificationBody::new);
            var newNotification = RoleNotification.builder()
                    .notificationBody(notificationBody)
                    .role(role)
                    .build();

            roleNotificationDao.saveAndFlush(newNotification);
            talentDao.findAll(predicate)
                    .forEach(talent -> {
                        var identity = TalentRoleNotificationIdentity.builder()
                                .talentId(talent.getId())
                                .roleNotificationId(newNotification.getId())
                                .build();
                        var talentRoleNotification = TalentRoleNotificationRelations.builder()
                                .identity(identity)
                                .roleNotification(newNotification)
                                .talent(talent)
                                .sent(false)
                                .build();
                        talentRoleNotification.setIdentity(identity);
                        talentRoleNotification.setTalent(talent);
                        talentRoleNotificationRelationsDao.save(talentRoleNotification);
                    });
            return dtoFactory.toInfo(newNotification);
        } else throw new RoleNotificationLimitReached();
    }
```

Scheduled method that sends out the notifications:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5)
public void sendRoleMessage() {
    var unsentNotificationIds = talentRoleNotificationRelationsDao.findAll(
            QTalentRoleNotificationRelations.talentRoleNotificationRelations.sent.isFalse()
                    .and(QTalentRoleNotificationRelations.talentRoleNotificationRelations.talent.notificationToken.isNotNull()),
            PageRequest.of(0, 50)
    );

    unsentNotificationIds.forEach(unsentNotification -> {
        var talent = unsentNotification.getTalent();
        var roleNotification = unsentNotification.getRoleNotification();
        markAsSent(unsentNotification);
        talentRoleNotificationRelationsDao.saveAndFlush(unsentNotification);
        notificationPusher.push(notificationFactory.buildComposite(talent.getNotificationToken()), dtoFactory.toInfo(roleNotification));
    });

}
```

The notificationPusher method itself:

```
@Override
public void push(PushMessageComposite composite, RoleNotificationInfo roleNotificationInfo) {
    String roleId = roleNotificationInfo.getRoleId();
    String title = "New matching role!";

    var push = Message.builder()
            .setToken(composite.getMeta().getDeviceToken())
            .setAndroidConfig(AndroidConfig.builder()
                    .setNotification(AndroidNotification.builder()
                            .setTitle(title)
                            .setBody(roleNotificationInfo.getBody())
                            .setSound(composite.getMeta().getSound())
                            .build())
                    .build())
            .setApnsConfig(ApnsConfig.builder()
                    .setAps(Aps.builder()
                            .setAlert(ApsAlert.builder()
                                    .setTitle(title)
                                    .setBody(roleNotificationInfo.getBody())
                                    .build())
                            .setBadge(composite.getMeta().getBadge().intValue())
                            .setSound(composite.getMeta().getSound())
                            .build())
                    .build())
            .putData("roleId", roleId)
            .build();

    Try.run(() -> FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().sendAsync(push).get())
            .onFailure(e -> {
                log.error("Firebase Cloud Messaging failed during sendNotification", e);
                var talent = talentDao.findTalentByNotificationToken(composite.getMeta().getDeviceToken());
                talent.setNotificationToken(null);
                talentDao.save(talent);
            });

}
```

And the dto factory mapper method:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
public RoleNotificationInfo toInfo(RoleNotification source) {
    return RoleNotificationInfo.builder()
            .id(source.getId())
            .body(source.getNotificationBody().getBody())
            .created(source.getCreated())
            .roleId(source.getRole().getId())
            .build();
}
```

I am unsure where the problem lies. I assume it is due to the high amount of users fetched from certain queries (20k+). I did some profiling, and this were the results:

[image: Profiler results]

Memory/CPU charts:

[image: Mem&CPU]

My question is, should this even be possible at all? Is there a different approach that would be much more efficient? Should I use an external service for this? Is the problem something very obvious that I do not see? I am not sure where to look. If anything in my code is unclear and needs further clarification, please let me know and I'll try to edit and format it the best way I can.

Comment: Your profiling results are useless, it shows no useful information and I guess you have no experience in proper profiling. However since you're doing a 20k user `findAll()`, it's a pretty safe bet that your problem is a classic "trying to fetch everything at once into memory" problem for which there are different solutions depending on your tech stack, but the common aspect is "process data in small batches".

Comment: @Kayaman How do I process this data in small batches? I need to assign everyone the proper notification immediatelly, and then send it out later. How would you go about solving this in batches, the tech stack including spring, hibernate, quartz, doesn't really matter. Would you include any external services?

Comment: This would probably be most efficient as a stored procedure. No use fetching the data on application side for processing just to save it back to DB.

Comment: @Kayaman What exactly would you store into the procedure? The process of fetching the talents and then creating the talent -> notification relation? How will I filter the users inside the stored procedure? The filtering of users is done via a searchToken that is mapped onto a filter class at the moment

Comment: The whole logic in `talentDao.findAll(predicate).forEach(...`. If you're (only) used to working with QueryDSL, this is where you realize that developer ease comes at performance price. You could also try to use offset pagination (QueryDSL should be able to do that probably) and work with batches of 1k or less entities, or any other mechanism that avoids loading all the entities in memory.

Comment: @Kayaman I have actually used queryDSL for this case only as it seemed to be the easiest way to incorporate a predicate. Not really a huge fan as I did notice that it comes with a very large performance price, as I have had other cases where writing a nativeQuery would do the job much better. Thank you for the help, I'll give it a shot.